# NullPointerException at OnDateSet, picking date from datepicker dialog android

Tags: android, time, nullpointerexception, datepicker

what i wanna do, its store the picked date from a datepicker, but when i click on ready button after selecting the date, crashes, and i dont know how to solve, im working on 4.2.2

```
public class grafica extends ActionBarActivity {
    public Calendar mCalendar;
    private XYPlot mySimpleXYPlot;
    private Button mDateButton;
    private int mMonth; 
    private int mDay; 
    private int mYear;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    static EditText DateEdit;
    DialogFragment dateFragment;
    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grafica);
        Button mDateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fecha);


        mDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDatePickerDialog(v);    
            }
        });  
     }
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        dateFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        dateFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

    }



    class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}
    public void updateDateButtonText() {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
            String dateForButton = dateFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime());
            mDateButton.setText(dateForButton);
        }

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
  mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
  mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
  mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
  updateDateButtonText();
    DateEdit.setText(day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
}
}
```

there is the console log

```
08-27 12:56:03.045: E/AndroidRuntime(22404): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 12:56:03.045: E/AndroidRuntime(22404): Process: com.example.dietdfreev2, PID: 22404
08-27 12:56:03.045: E/AndroidRuntime(22404): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-27 12:56:03.045: E/AndroidRuntime(22404):    at         com.example.dietdfreev2.grafica$DatePickerFragment.onDateSet(grafica.java:116)
08-27 12:56:03.045: E/AndroidRuntime(22404):    at android.app.DatePickerDialog.tryNotifyDateSet(DatePickerDialog.java:148)
08-27 12:56:03.045: E/AndroidRuntime(22404):    at android.app.DatePickerDialog.onClick(DatePickerDialog.java:116)
08-27 12:56:03.045: E/AndroidRuntime(22404):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
08-27 12:56:03.045: E/AndroidRuntime(22404):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-27 12:56:03.045: E/AndroidRuntime(22404):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-27 12:56:03.045: E/AndroidRuntime(22404):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
08-27 12:56:03.045: E/AndroidRuntime(22404):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 12:56:03.045: E/AndroidRuntime(22404):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-27 12:56:03.045: E/AndroidRuntime(22404):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
08-27 12:56:03.045: E/AndroidRuntime(22404): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
08-27 12:56:03.045: E/AndroidRuntime(22404):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's line grafica.java:116?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you didn't initialize `mCalendar`,i.e. `mCalendar` is null.So initialize it as

```
mCalendar  = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Rewrite your code as

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grafica);

        mCalendar  = Calendar.getInstance();  // add here
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the date to the date picker dialog initially !!!

i think this can be helpful.

```
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateLabel();
        }

    };



OnCreateView(){


datetext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), date, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }

        });

}

// To update date on click
    private void updateLabel() {
        String myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"; // In which you need put here
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.GERMAN);
        EditText datetext = (EditText) mainlayout
                .findViewById(R.id.ewbl_maintenance_date);
        datetext.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
    }
```